# How can I convert an IntPtr into a Boolean[] in C#?

Tags: c#, c, arrays, marshalling, intptr

**Background Information**

I have a function in C which return me a `void*`.

I started testing the convert between the two projects, assigning `true` or `false` to the pointer, back in C# I got the `IntPtr`, and I used the `IntPtr.ToPointer()` function and then just cast it into a byte, which according to what I read is the equivalent to boolean in c#.

This worked for me just fine.

DLLIMPORT:

```
[DllImport(Library.ruta,
SetLastError = true,
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static IntPtr test_boolean(int flag);
```

Using the Function:

```
x = Library.test_boolean(1);

z = x.ToPointer();
Console.WriteLine("Prueba");

if (Convert.ToBoolean((byte)z))
    Console.WriteLine("True");
else
    Console.WriteLine("False");
```

**Problem**
When I tried to do the same but assigning a boolean array to the pointer, I haven't been able to get it back in C#.

This is how the function in C looks like

```
...
vpointer *chromosome;

chromosome = s_malloc(2*sizeof(boolean *));


if (flag == 1)
{
    chromosome[0] = true;
    chromosome[1] = true;
}
...
Return chromosome;
```

What I tried to do in C#:

(1) I tried the same "casting", this time to a byte array. That gave me a null reference exception:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(((byte*)z)[1]))
    Console.WriteLine("True");
else
    Console.WriteLine("False");
```

(2) As that didn't worked, and after some research I tried the `Marshal.Copy` function, to copy my pointer to a byte array. Eventhough this time I'm not getting any exception I'm not getting the righ results. I mean, for instance if the first boolean of the array is false im getting true.

This is how the C# code looks like:

```
x = Library.test_boolean(1);

byte [] managedArray = new byte[2];

Marshal.Copy(x, managedArray, 0, 2);

foreach (var qq in managedArray)
{
    Boolean a = Convert.ToBoolean(qq);
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
}
```

**Question**
So my question is what is the correct way to convert from an IntPtr in C# to a Boolean array?

Comment: 2*sizeof(boolean *));   should be 2*sizeof(boolean));

Comment: (thanks) I've just changed it,  but I still keep getting it wrong back in C#

Comment: @Laggel As Mitch pointed out, boolean, not boolean*. The array you want should fit two booleans, not two pointers to booleans. It won't be the reason for the crash though.

Comment: @Laggel Could you add the DllImport/declaration of the `test_boolean` function?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I've just added the dllimport. Note: back in C# the return type is `vpointer` which is just a custom type for `void*`

Answer (score 2):

> … assigning `true` or `false` to the pointer, back in C# I got the `IntPtr`, and I used the `IntPtr.ToPointer()` function and then just cast it into a byte …

That's just wrong, even if it may have worked. If the return type is `void*`, then it actually should be a pointer, not a boolean value. And if you really want to perform this atrocity, then you don't need the intermediate step with pointer, you can cast `IntPtr` directly to a `byte`.

Now, to your actual question: if you know that the function will always return array of two booleans, I think it would be best if you declared it as returning `bool[]` in C# with appropriate attribute (something like `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I1, SizeConst=2)]`).

But your C# code should work too. I think the problem is in your C code: The array you're returning is declared as `vpointer*`, which, according to your comment, is equivalent to `void**`. That means that on 32-bit machine, the C compiler treats this variable as an array of 4-byte values. If you want it to treat it as array of 1-byte values, you need to declare it as such (e.g. `boolean *chromosome;`).

Comment: **First** *if you really want to perform this atrocity*, I don't want to perform an atrocity. Why is that an atrocity? and what would be the correct way? (Sorry for the newbie questions).   

**Second** I cannot marshal it like that because in the real scenario is not gonna be a fixed value.  

**Third** I'm doing this tests just because I need to use a function from a library which I cannot change, that is returning me a `vpointer**` but I don't know how to handle it. The point is I cannot change that library to `boolean *chromosome`.

Comment: but according to your comment would it be correct to do something like this:  
` 
var length = 2 * 4;
            byte[] managedArray = new byte[length];

            x = Gaul.test_boolean(1);

            Marshal.Copy(x, managedArray, 0, length);

            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToBoolean(managedArray, 0 * 4));
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToBoolean(managedArray, 1 * 4));
`

Comment: I meant that atrocity is having a pointer that's not actually a pointer. That's working directly against what the type system is for.

Comment: So, it's returning `void***`? Why so much indirection? What does that value contain? How would you handle it from C?

Comment: 1) The original one yes it's void*** (but I'm not there yet, I would like to know how to handle every level.
2) I don't know 
3) it contains a matrix of values, the data type of the matrix values is set in runtime so it could be either a boolean matrix or a doubles one, etc.
4) In C as far as I see, they always cast the pointer before using it.

Comment: If you have array of arrays of booleans, it would make sense to represent it as `void**`, but not `void***`. Could you include a sample code that uses the “matrix” in C?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16743/discussion-between-laggel-and-svick)